# z order of surface listbox item

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I am trying to bring the focus on the clicked item of the surface listbox. For WPF I had a similar post and it worked after setting the trigger property of    . 
The full xaml code is available at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5d486826-9a72-4769-bd09-ff6977e16c30/#cd2cd9af-abbf-40ca-9e30-4684ee2a2eb2

I tried doing the same in the xaml code for a surface button which is put as item in surface listbox, nothing happens. Basically, my listbox contains surface buttons and when any button is clicked, it scales up i.e. the size of it increases. The only issue is that next item overlaps the scaled item because of the z-order issue. For the normal WPF listbox and button control above code did the trick but its not happening for surface application.

Would appreciate any help/directions in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.. Had posted on MSDN and it finally worked by setting the zIndex of the surfaceListbox instead of the content of the item which was a surfacebutton.

**http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/970877bd-2960-4f0e-a203-1d357bbd55ce/#4a08e54b-5055-4a66-ad75-762ee88ef303**